# set -e with multiple subshells. non-blocking wait -n

Tags: bash

In a CI setting, I'd like to run multiple jobs in the background, and use `set -e` to exit on the first error.

This requires using `wait -n` instead of `wait`, but for increasing throughput I'd then want to move the `for i in {1..20}; do wait -n; done` to the end of the script.

Unfortunately, this means that it is hard to track the errors.

Rather, what I would want is to do the equivalent to a non-blocking `wait -n` often, and exit as soon as possible.

Is this possible or do I have to write my bash scripts as a `Makefile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Alternative Approach: Emulate `set -e` for background jobs

Instead of checking the jobs all the time it could be easier and more efficient to exit the script directly when a job fails. To this end, append `... || kill $$` to every job you start:

```
# before
myCommand &
myProgram arg1 arg2 &

# after
myCommand || kill $$ &
myProgram arg1 arg2 || kill $$ &
```

## Non-Blocking `wait -n`

If you really have to, you can write your own non-blocking `wait -n` with a little trick:

```sh
nextJobExitCode() {
    sleep 0.1 &
    wait -n
    exitCode="$?"
    kill %%
    return "$exitCode"
}
```

The function `nextJobExitCode` waits at most 0.1 seconds for your jobs. If none of your jobs were already finished or did finish in that 0.1 seconds, `nextJobExitCode` will terminate with exit code 0.

#### Example usage

```sh
set -e

sleep 1 &            # job 1
(sleep 3; false) &   # job 2

nextJobExitCode      # won't exit. No jobs finished yet
sleep 2
nextJobExitCode      # won't exit. Job 1 finished with 0
sleep 2
nextJobExitCode      # will exit! Job 2 finished with 1
```

Comment: I really like your alternative approach, as that solves the problem "exit as soon as possible".  The first approach seems less useful.  Could you reverse the order in the anwer?

Comment: @user239558 Done.